# Is it possible to add a ENV Var via App manifest.yml in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

The question seems clear. 
I was unable to get info on that.

The way I can use for instance is :

```
$ vmc push myapp --no-start
$ vmc env-add myapp MYVAR=var 
$ vmc start myapp
```

So, it's possible to configure that in my manifest.yml, and in which way ?

I would set NODE_ENV="production"

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

With the latest VMC (gem install vmc --pre, mkdir ~/.vmc/use-ng), have this in your manifest alongside the app attributes like name, instances, etc.:

```
env:
  NODE_ENV: production
```

Not sure about legacy VMC, sorry.

Comment: When you talking about vmc -pre (which pre release you talk about ?)
What are your current version?
I 'm (on the 16-Oct) on 0.3.18. The 0.3.21 is the actual standard one. But troubleshot with login, so i 'm in 0.3.18

Comment: It's not work as It for me in vmc 0.3.18 and vcap as build '2222'.
Still looking.